# UIView animation - Objective-C. Will this animation cause a stack overflow exception?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, objective-c-blocks

I have a method with three animation blocks, which animates two `UIImageViews`. Will this code cause a stack overflow exception in the future?

I mean recursive blocks. I need to animate them by order. The first big image should fade in, then a smaller image should fade in, and then both images should fade out, and animation should start again.

```
- (void)startAnimation {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [_bigImage setAlpha:1];
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            [_mediumImage setAlpha:1];
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished1) {

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
                [_mediumImage setAlpha:0];
                [_bigImage setAlpha:0];
            }
            completion:^(BOOL finished3) {

              [self startAnimation];
            }];
        }];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Don't do that. Use a group animation.

Comment: @dasdom, can you show me how? i need to animate them by order, first big image should fade in, then smaller image should fade in, and then all 2 images should fade out, and animation should start again

Comment: Apple can: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH3-SW15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you posted should work fine. Yes, you could also do it using CAAnimations, but those are harder to figure out.

I disagree with dasdom. I think your current approach is reasonable.

I do find nested `animateWithDuration:` methods to be hard to figure out. It's easy to get lost in the nested block syntax.

Instead, you could add an integer or enum instance variable that keeps track of the animation step, and have your method invoke different animation code for each step, then call itself again in each animation block:

In your header:

```
typedef enum 
{
  first,
  second,
  third,
  done
} animationSteps

@interface MyClass
{
  animationSteps currentStep
}
```

The .m file:

```
- (void)doAnimation 
{

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^
  {
    switch (currentStep)
    {
      case first:
        [_bigImage setAlpha:1];
        break;
      case second:
        [_mediumImage setAlpha:1];
        break;
      case third:
        [_mediumImage setAlpha:0];
        [_bigImage setAlpha:0];
        break;
    }
  } 
  completion:^(BOOL finished) 
  {
    currentStep++;
    if (currentStep == done)
      currentStep = first;
    [self doAnimation];
  }
  ]; 
}
```

Comment: Cool, but it will cause to stackoverflow exception?

Comment: No. Apple's animation methods operate asynchronously. The first call returns before the completion block gets called.